# Microsoft JQuery Template plugin: Script Stack Space Quota is Exhausted

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-plugins, firefox3.6

I read a few questions regarding the Firefox "Script Stack Space Quota is Exhausted."  The answers are usually "work with less data".

However, how much "JSON" data we process is not the issue.  We created a very small template, then loaded over 700 products with that template without an issue.

The problem seem to be how much HTML is in the template (times the quantity of products).

In our case, it's how much html content is rendered with the Microsoft Templating plugin.

Is there some setting we could do within MS Template or Firefox's preferences to avoid the Script Stack error?

Comment: It's probable that Firefox has a 100 megabyte limit on HTML rendered content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading and displaying all 700 items at once? If not, you can just get the subset of the items for each page (or whatever) of items. If so, I'd recommend changing to a paged system. :P

Comment: Is there any way to tell MS Template to only render a subset of data?  I guess I could objectArray.filter(paging) on client then send that set to MS Template.

Comment: I assume if you just sent it a subset, it would only render that. I'm not sure how you'd handle sending it the page number and what-not, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and had to limit my results until I found a "sweet spot"...in my case, about 300 results.